# How to display an alertdialog on top of other alertdialog? And when one in foreground is closed, then the one in background should be visible

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This is my code to edit/update which I am doing throgh a custom alertdialog which contains the data fetched frm database. Now when the inputs provided are incorrect I want to show other alertdialog on top of this providing some message to user. When the user dismisses this message alertdialog, the previous one which is used for update should be visible. How can I do that?

```
public class CountryEdit extends ListActivity{

    private Long mRowId;
    private CountryDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "assignment2.demos.MyCountriesCP";
    public static final String uriString = "content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME +"/countries";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(uriString);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();


        Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, getIntent().getExtras().getString("SORT_ORDER"));       
        String[] from = new String[] { "year", "country" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.year, R.id.country };       
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_row,
                                        c, from, to);       
        setListAdapter(sca);

        mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(assignment2.demos.MyCountriesActivity.KEY_ROWID) 
                : null;
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(assignment2.demos.MyCountriesActivity.KEY_ROWID) 
                    : null;
        }

        populateFields();
    }



    private void populateFields() {

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_country, null);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().
                            appendPath(String.valueOf(mRowId)).build(), null, null, null, null);

        /* Read alert input */
        final EditText editCountry =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editCountry);
        final EditText editYear =(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.editYear);
            editCountry.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("country")));
            editYear.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("year")));

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Edit country/year")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {

                            String country = editCountry.getText().toString();

                            if(country.trim().length()>0 && editYear.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){   
                                int year = Integer.parseInt(editYear.getText().toString());
                                ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();

                                updateValues.put(mDbHelper.COUNTRY, country);
                                updateValues.put(mDbHelper.YEAR, year);
                                getContentResolver().update(
                                            CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(String.valueOf(mRowId)).build(), updateValues, null, null);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else{   
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(CountryEdit.this)
                                    .setTitle("Invalid Inputs!")
                                    .setMessage("You need to enter Country AND Year.")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // here you can add functions
                                        finish();
                                     }
                                  }).show();


//                              Toast.makeText(CountryEdit.this,
//                                      "You need to enter Country AND Year.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //finish();
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
                            // ignore, just dismiss
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first alert dialog is dismissing itself when the second is about to show (when the click listener finishes). You can't avoid that.

There's a dirty hack where you can override the click listener created by the builder like this:

```
create().getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener( ... }
```

But I don't recommend to do that if you don't know what you're doing (it might break the internet ;-).
You would have to dismiss the dialog yourself. If you don't do that it will never close, the user will see it forever and would have to kill your app to get it started again.